# Node & python don't return the same hash256

Tags: python, node.js, sha256, hmac

My NodeJS & Python scripts don't return the same hash, what could cause this issue?

Node.js

```
const { createHmac } = require("crypto");
var message = 'v1:1583197109:'
var key = 'Asjei8578FHasdjF85Hfjkasi875AsjdiAas_CwueKL='
const digest = Buffer.from(key, "base64");
const hash = createHmac("sha256", digest)
  .update(message)
  .digest("hex");

console.log(hash)
> 7655b4f816dc7725fb4507a20f2b97823979ea00b121c84b76924fea167dcaf7
```

Python3

```
message = 'v1:1583197109:'
key = 'Asjei8578FHasdjF85Hfjkasi875AsjdiAas_CwueKL=' + '=' #add a "=" to avoid incorrect padding
digest = base64.b64decode(key.encode('utf-8'))
hash_ = hmac.new(digest, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
hash_result = hash_.hexdigest()
print(hash_result)
> c762b612d7c56d3f9c95052181969b42c604c2d41b7ce5fc7f5a06457e312d5b
```

I guess it could be the extra **=** to avoid the incorrect padding but my *key* ends with a single **=**.

Comment: Are you sure you posted correct code? Python example gives another different hash for me...

Comment: `I guess it could be the extra =` - firstly, don't guess - **test**. And I tested it and it changes nothing (if the key encoding is present - without it the padding is needed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js `Buffer.from(..., 'base64')` can consume the input in the "urlsafe" base64 (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings), and `_` is not a valid Base64 character for python, while it is for node.

Adding `altchars` that correspond to the "urlsafe" version of Base64 to python code yields equal hashes.

```js
const { createHmac } = require("crypto");
var message = 'v1:1583197109:'
var key = 'Asjei8578FHasdjF85Hfjkasi875AsjdiAas_CwueKL='

const digest = Buffer.from(key, "base64");
const hash = createHmac("sha256", digest)
  .update(message)
  .digest("hex");

console.log(hash) // 7655b4f816dc7725fb4507a20f2b97823979ea00b121c84b76924fea167dcaf7
```

```py
message = 'v1:1583197109:'
key = 'Asjei8578FHasdjF85Hfjkasi875AsjdiAas_CwueKL=' + '=' #add a "=" to avoid incorrect padding
digest = base64.b64decode(key.encode('utf-8'), altchars='-_')
hash_ = hmac.new(digest, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
hash_result = hash_.hexdigest()
print(hash_result) # 7655b4f816dc7725fb4507a20f2b97823979ea00b121c84b76924fea167dcaf7
```

Also, python's `b64decode` has `validate` kwarg, which would check the input string and "fail loud" instead of ignoring incorrect characters

Comment: According to the documentation, the length of `altchars` should be at least 2.